# React useEffect is not being called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to set up a system where when the system mounts onSnapshot is not called. However, once system has mounted useEffect can run onSnapshot, if something in the database changes. However, even when I add something in the database onSnapshot is not called in the useEffect, it doesn't even gets in the useEffect block.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
            console.log("Dashboard mounted");
             onSnapshot(collection(db, 'announcements'), async (snapshot) => {
                console.log("BRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR")
                let oldData = announcementsData;
                let temp = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                // sort temp by id in descending order
                temp.sort((a, b) => {
                    return b.id - a.id;
                }
                );
                dispatch(addAnnouncements(temp));

                // console.log(oldData.length !== temp.length && oldData.length !== 0)
                if (oldData.length !== temp.length && oldData.length !== 0) {
                    await schedulePushNotification(temp[0].title, temp[0].description);
                }
                setAnnouncementsData(temp);

            })
        }
        else {
            isMounted.current = true;
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: It looks like `if(isMounted.current)` should be `if(!isMounted.current)`. Although you should generally use state for that sort of thing, not refs. And you shouldn't need a check at all, as useEffect will only run once (with the empty dependency array you provided it)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if (isMounted.current)` check from your `useEffect` since it doesn't have any effect on mounting the dashboard, especially since `useEffect` function only gets called once due to the empty dependency array:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    
            console.log("Dashboard mounted");
             onSnapshot(collection(db, 'announcements'), async (snapshot) => {
                console.log("BRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR")
                let oldData = announcementsData;
                let temp = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                // sort temp by id in descending order
                temp.sort((a, b) => {
                    return b.id - a.id;
                }
                );
                dispatch(addAnnouncements(temp));

                // console.log(oldData.length !== temp.length && oldData.length !== 0)
                if (oldData.length !== temp.length && oldData.length !== 0) {
                    await schedulePushNotification(temp[0].title, temp[0].description);
                }
                setAnnouncementsData(temp);

            })
            isMounted.current = true
        
    }, []);
```